# product is showing free shipping eventhough the coupon is not enter

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I have set up a cart price rule: if coupon "freeshipping" is enter, and any of the product A/B/C is in the cart, the shipping will be free, plus 5% discount.

The issue i'm having now is that without using the coupon code, the product A/B/C still showing free shipping when added to cart.

Also, even if i disabled all the cart price ruls on the site, the product A/B/C still shows free shipping, even though it does not meet the free shipping minimum set on the site.

======================================================

below is the setting for the cart price rule:

```
Condition: left blank

Actions:
Apply Discount Amount 5
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 0
Apply to Shipping Amount 
Discount amount is applied to subtotal only
Discard subsequent rules 
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).

If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is  ProductA
SKU  is  ProductB
SKU  is  ProductC

Free Shipping "For matching items only"
```

Comment: what is the coupon setting?

Comment: coupon setting is mentioned above: Condition: left blank

Actions:
Apply Discount Amount 5
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 0
Apply to Shipping Amount 
Discount amount is applied to subtotal only
Discard subsequent rules 
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).

If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is  ProductA
SKU  is  ProductB
SKU  is  ProductC

Free Shipping "For matching items only"

Comment: what about the option that say coupon? do you require coupon for the rule to work or it is set to "no coupon" required?

Comment: it's set to "specific coupon".